# What is tableresource(9) of type (pgsql result)

Tags: php, postgresql, resources

```
$sql = "insert into my_table ...";
$rs = pg_query($rs);
var_dump($rs); // => tableresource(9) of type (pgsql result)
```

What's this? object? array? How can I use it?

The row is inserted in the table.

The PHP doc page should be improved in this regard. The page http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query.php says that:

> Return Values
>   A query result resource on success or FALSE on failure.

There should be a link ***result resource*** explaining what it is ...

Comment: What question are you trying to ask?  Talk to the PHP people about improving their documentation.  Don't mush the two issues together.  Also define the "this" of which you speak

Comment: If you had read the title of the topic you would know what "this" is. And I just mention the PHP doc, because maybe someone can see this here and change. Many people here in Stackoverflow try to look too smart, but can't provide a simple answer or links. I just want to know how to extract what is inside tableresource(9).

Answer (score 1):

Um, did you even look at the documentation you linked?
It shows a plain example... straight from the page you linked

```
$result = pg_query($conn, "SELECT author, email FROM authors");
if (!$result) {
  echo "An error occured.\n";
  exit;
}

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo "Author: $row[0]  E-mail: $row[1]";
  echo "<br />\n";
}
```

It is a resource that you can iterate over, which will give you an array.

**EDIT**

For an insert statement, null will be returned if it was unsuccesful. If it  is succesful, you can use it to get the insert id by doign

```
$res = pg_query("INSERT INTO test VALUES (1)");

$id = pg_last_oid($res);
```

You never actually do something with a resource itself, but generally pass it to another function.

You can also get the error for the query by

```
echo pg_result_error($res)
```

`pg_result_status` also uses it

Comment: Hi. Thank you, but this is an example for the select statement. This doesn't work for the insert statement. I tried it, and it doesn't even enter the while loop.

Comment: I updated my post with what you can use the resource for on an insert statement